# How can I get on click event in doInBackground in asynctask in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to read from edit text in socket programming. I have a do in background, which creates a socket and read from it. I want to read continuously from it, when a button is clicked. My program goes like:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "CLIENT_MESSAGE";
    EditText ip_address;
    EditText port_number;
    EditText message_client;
    Button button_send;
    Button button_cancel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void connect(View view) {
//        ip_address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ip_address);
//        ip_address.setText("192.168.9.100");
//        port_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.port_number);
//        port_number.setText("8080");
        message_client = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message_client);
        button_send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_send);
        button_cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_cancel);
        Log.d(TAG, "connecting to the server.");
//        new ConnectToServer(ip_address.getText().toString(), port_number.getText().toString(), message_client,button_send,button_cancel).execute();
        new ConnectToServer(this,"192.168.9.100","8080", message_client,button_send,button_cancel).execute();

    }
}

class ConnectToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, DataOutputStream, Void> {
    private static final String TAG = "CLIENT_MESSAGE";
    String ip_address;
    int port_number;
    EditText message_client;
    Button button_send;
    Button button_cancel;
    boolean send = false;
    boolean cancel = false;
    Activity activity;

    public ConnectToServer(Activity activity,String ip_address, String port_number, EditText message_client,Button button_send,Button button_cancel) {
        this.ip_address = ip_address;
        this.port_number = Integer.parseInt(port_number);
        this.message_client = message_client;
        this.button_cancel = button_cancel;
        this.button_send = button_send;
        this.activity = activity;
        ;
    }



    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket(ip_address, port_number);

            if (LoggerConfig.TAG) {
                Log.d(TAG, "the socket is created at " + ip_address);
            }

            final DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            publishProgress(output);

            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (LoggerConfig.TAG) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Could not connect.");
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(DataOutputStream... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        while (true )
        {
            //how would I get the on click events here?
        }

    }
}
```

I have to buttons, send and cancel. How can I send the data to the server, when send button is clicked? And, close the socket when cancel is clicked?

Comment: AsyncTask is not so good for tasks that need to be *paused* and *resumed*, if that is what you are trying to do. If you just want to cancel it, you can do it from outside the AsyncTask class, with AsyncTask.cancel(true) .

Answer (score 0):

**onProgressUpdate is called on UI thread** to publish the updates on it. From your question what I have understood is  you want click events for button...why don't you use **button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {/* Some Code */ });**.Correct me if I am wrong.

If that is not the case then you should create your own listener and attach it on asyctask and activity...let me know if you want it this way, I will add snippet

Comment: When button is clicked, how can I use set on click listenter? I need to be in on progress update at that time. But once on progress update is finished, I return to doinbackground, from where I can't access button set on click

Comment: If that is not the case then you should create your own listener and attach it on asyctask and activity...let me know if you want it this way, I will add snippet : Please provide me snippet.